# How do I backup dynamodb using python?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a quick way of backing up dynamodb tables to JSON files using a python script with [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this handy [dynamodump](https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump) tool which is python based (uses [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto)) to dump the tables into JSON files.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a `PynamoDB`-based tool called `dynamodb-dumper` (and its counterpart `dynamodb-loader`) which will dump a table with multiple processes using the parallel scan method offered by the DynamoDB API. People have found it 10x faster than single threaded tools such as `dynamodump`.

It's available with `pip install dynamodb_utils` or on github at https://github.com/adamchainz/dynamodb_utils.